# How to filter for a value that is sometimes undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an application with a tree structure to certain objects.  Each object has an id, and may have a parent.

Unfortunately, the obvious filter of "{_id:current}" doesn't work properly when the current ID is undefined (e. g. at the root level).  It works fine when current is set, breaks down when it's not.

Can I write an expression that will match undefined as appropriate *and* the actual value?

E. G.:

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat='item in list | filter:{parent:current_item_id}'>
        <a ng-click='current_item_id = item._id'>{{ item }}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

If the answer is "You can't", that's fine; I've written a customer filter that does something 'close enough'.  It's not as flexible as the built in 'filter' filter, but doesn't need to be.

Per request, some sample json data:

```
{
    "items":[
        {'_id':1,'name':"Parent 1"},
        {'_id':2,'name':"Parent 2"},
        {'_id':3,'name':"Child 1", "parent":1},
        {'_id':4,'name':"Child 2", "parent":2}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your json?

Comment: @Dvir done!  Sample json added.

Comment: I tried to solve with expression with no luck. But you can use a function comparator instead of directive for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom filter to filter accordingly, Kindly modify it if you are expecting something little different

```
angular.module('app').filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(array, current_id) {
    return (array || []).filter(function(item) {
      if (typeof item.parent == 'undefined') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return item.parent == current_id;
      }
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid writing a custom filter -- already done a slightly more generic version of this.  It just seems like there 'should' be a way to do this that doesn't involve custom filters.  It's just an equality operator where one side of the equation is occasionally 'undefined'.